# Motivation for the study of the Chern connection

Tags: differential-geometry, applications, motivation, holomorphic-bundles

Given a Hermitian metric $H$ over a holomorphic vector bundle $E$ with holomorphic structure $\overline{\partial}$, there exists a unique connection $\nabla$ (named afer Chern) satisying the following conditions:

1) $\nabla$ is a $H$-connection, i.e H is parallel with respect to $\nabla$,

2) $\nabla^{0,1} = \overline{\partial}$

My question is, what motivates all this? Do you know any application of this? I mean not only in other fields, I am interested also in its role in geometry.

Thank you all for your invaluable help!

Comment: The simplest answer is that it's analogous to the Levi-Civita connection in Riemannian geometry. What's amazing is that the complex structure allows a unique such connection for all hermitian vector bundles on a complex manifold, not just the tangent bundle. (By the way, despite having been a student of Chern's, I have never before seen this attributed to him!)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Anyway, Moroianu [pag 25, Th4.3 http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/~moroianu/tex/kg.pdf] calls it Chern connection, I thought it was one of the standard way to refer to it :) . So, one of the important properties for which we are interested in this connection is that it is "naturally associated" with the complex structure?

Comment: I think the name is actually pretty standard, at least I can think of many texts that use it.

Comment: What does it mean for $H$ to be parallel with respect to $\nabla$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chern connection coincides with the Levi–Civita connection if and only if
$h$ is Kähler. ($h$ is the hermitian metric such that $H(X,Y) = h(X,Y) -ih(JX,Y)$)

Answer (score 3):

One important application is twisted Dolbeault-cohomology. Choosing the chern connection on a bundle allows to extend $ \bar \partial $ on the antiholomorphic differential forms to the bundle $ \Lambda ^{0,\bullet} \otimes E $ s.th. the extension $ \bar \partial_E $ satisfies $ \bar \partial_E^2=0 $. So you can define twisted version of dolbeault-cohomology.

Comment: Isn't this just the definition of a holomorphic structure? I don't see where you need the chern connection for this.